# Images served from private files dir unprintable in IE11

Tags: 7, files

[IE 7 - 10 have been killed off](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/01/windows-8-internet-explorer-7-8-9-and-10-mostly-consigned-to-the-dustbin-of-history/). Please somebody kill ie11 too.

I have a D7 site that stores images in file fields in `private://`. IE11 fetches these images appropriately and displays them in normal website use, however when you come to print them, they're not there. Instead you just see a tiny photo icon and "Photo"!

[image: screenshot]

The same image copied somewhere public and referenced there works fine - seems to be something about the way Drupal serves the request for private files.

It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Edge. Unfortunately I *need* ie11 to be able to print these images. Has anyone found this to be a problem, and has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: Does this work? http://its.yale.edu/how-to/article-printing-web-page-background-colors-and-images

Comment: No, this is not a background image.